# Call a function on any event of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to call a signle function on any event happens for `<textarea>`.

How do I achieves this.

Please do suggest me folks, jquery is preferable.

Thanks,

-Pravin

Comment: Why to use all events? if you can find each suitable events here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Trying to act on any event of an element does not make much sense because you would have to implement another layer of event type filtering in your code, thus defeating the purpose. I suppose you have your reasons, but I think you may be skipping possible simple solutions to your actual problem.

Comment: Yes...you are right Guillaume...I will use same as ur suggestion, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$("textarea").each(
                        function(element) {

                            $(element).bind({

                                focusin: function() {
                                    $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-focus');
                                },
                                focusout: function() {
                                    $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-focus');
                                }
                            });

                        }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#textarea_id').change(function(){
  // your code...
});
```

That code will run when text of textarea changes. If you want, you can also run the code when key is pressed with `keyup` or `keypress` event:

```
$('#textarea_id').keypress(function(){
  // your code...
});
```